# PYTHON How to continue code formatted by input result?

Tags: python, input

I have this assignment in my Python beginners course.

I have this code:

```
questOne =  input("How many geese flocks have you seen?: ")
while not questOne.isnumeric():
        questOne =  input("How many geese flocks have you seen?: ")
```

Now I need to ask depending on the amount of geese flocks, to assign a name to the flock and the amount of birds in that flock. 
For Example:

How many geese flocks have you seen? 2
Insert 1. geese flock …
… name: Geeseflock1
… amount of birds: 200
Insert 2. geese flock …
… name: Geeseflock2
… amount of birds: 100

So. How can I ask those questions depending on the integer inserted in the first question?

Comment: You need to loop over the input value, `for i in range(1, int(questOne)+1):` you can then use `i` in your next `input()`

Comment: Please review your textbook or other course materials.